# Angular 4 - HTTP Request

Tags: angular, typescript, request

Trying to make a HTTP GET request but no values are displaying or logging nor any errors. I've console logged "res" and "taskData".

!TASK COMPONENT!

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
selector: 'app-task',
templateUrl: './task.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./task.component.css']
})
export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {
tasks: Object;

constructor(private http: Http) {}

ngOnInit() {

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/task', { headers: headers })
.map((res) => { res.json().subscribe((taskData) => {
    this.tasks = taskData
   })
  })
 }
}


// Back-End Node HTTP
router.get('/task', (req, res) => {
models.task.findAll().then((taskData) => {
return res.json(taskData)
  });
});
```

Comment: PLease post console.log(taskData) form node side

Comment: No errors show on node when console.log(taskData). But errors stated below where from chrome console

Comment: Want to see data, what is coming from node

Comment: // Back-End Node HTTP
router.get('/task', (req, res) => {
models.task.findAll().then((taskData) => {
return res.json(taskData)
  });
});

Comment: not code man , data , data , data I want to see data

Comment: the response of models.task.findAll()

Comment: @CristianHerrera just now i posted my answer. hope it will be helpfull